# Why does Ruby on Rails append an empty object when has_many and belongs_to are in use?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, arrays, paperclip, has-many

Hey, I am writing a website similar to 4chan. I have two models: `Board` and `Picture`. A `Board` has many `Picture`s:

```
class Board < ActiveRecord::Base

  # Relationships
  has_many :pictures, :dependent => :destroy

end
class Picture < ActiveRecord::Base

  # Relationships
  belongs_to :board

end
```

I do this in my view `boards/show.html.haml`:

```
- if @board.pictures.any?
  - @board.pictures.each do |picture|
    %article.picture-article{ :id => "picture-#{picture.id}" }
      - if picture.title?
        %header
          %h2= picture.title
      %img{ :src => picture.pic.url, :alt => (picture.title? ? picture.title : 'untitled pic') }/
      %pre~ picture.description
- else
  meh this board is still empty
```

And in my nice `BoardsController`:

```
def show
  @board = Board.find_by_short_name params[:id]
end
```

---

The problem is that always one `Picture` is shown which is empty. For example, I have a `Board` with no `Picture`s in the db (checked it with `Picture.all`), but this is the output:

```
<article class='picture-article' id='picture-'>
  <img alt='untitled pic' src='/pics/original/missing.png'>
  <pre></pre>
</article>
```

---

However, when I render it as JSON, the output is with no `Picture`s, like it should be:

```
{
  "board": {
    "name": "n00bs",
    "created_at": "2011-03-16T17:14:32Z",
    "updated_at": "2011-03-16T17:14:32Z",
    "id": 14,
    "short_name": "0",
    "pictures": [
    ]
  }
}
```

---

I can remove this by simply removing the last item of the array before doing an `each` but the bug still remains and this is super duper clumsy. How can this happen? Why does `@board.pictures` always append an empty `Picture` object?

Comment: On a side note, since you're using HTML5, please give up appending the picture's id to the id of the html element and use a custom data attribute instead, e.g. `%article.picture_article{"data-picture-id" => "#{picture.id}"}`. For more [here](http://html5doctor.com/html5-custom-data-attributes/).

Comment: have you tried using <%= unless @board.pictures.empty? %>

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ha!

In my view, adding `.all` did the job (and `order` also works):

```
- @board.pictures.all.each do |picture|
```

Answer (score 0):

Try pictures.present? instead of .any?

Comment: Still does not work, but it seems that Ruby thinks there are **any** pictures **present**. I can't figure out why, since there are no pictures present. I have also tried it with a clean DB and only some boards but it still appends an empty picture.